# How to search for lightweight JS packages (alternative libs to replace my libs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lib

I've been told there is some websites to look for lightweight libs alternatives for JS / Node.js. Can you advise some resources? Googling doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you're just looking for a framework comparison, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) has a page with some of the high-level details.

Comment: For example, I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv
but I think there are gonne be better libs, doing the same job in less time. How can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the cost of adding a npm package to your bundle. you have there similar packages section.
[bundlephobia](https://bundlephobia.com/)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect !!!